# AMAZON SNS / SMS , sending sms , delivery status

Tags: php, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am using amazon PHP SDK to try to send sms I am using following code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sdk = new Aws\Sns\SnsClient([
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => ['key' => 'xxx', 'secret' => 'xxx']
  ]);

$result = $sdk->publish([
    'Message' => 'This is a test message.',
    'PhoneNumber' => '+123456789',
    'MessageAttributes' => ['AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
         'DataType' => 'String',
         'StringValue' => 'testing sms'
      ]
  ]]);

print_r( $result );
```

My question is how do I get delivery Status back to an endpoint url HTTPS or HTTP?
like the sms got delivered or failed? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this today is to leverage the CloudWatch API (e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html) to read the logs delivered to your log groups